# integer comparison doesn't work in if statement (vhdl)

Tags: integer, comparison, vhdl

What is the error in the following code?

In the testbench `x` is set to `"00001111"`, yet the else branch is executed (in the simulation all of `y`'s bits are set to high impedance state, but `y` should equal `x`). I'm using `XILNX ISE Design Suite` and `ISim` as simulation environment. Thanks in advance.

```
entity test is
    Port ( x : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           y : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end test;

architecture Behavioral of test is

signal tmp : integer;

begin

process(x)
begin
tmp <= to_integer(unsigned(x(3 downto 0)));
if tmp = 15 then
    y <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(tmp, 8));
else
    y <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tmp` is a signal, thus it takes a delta delay before it reveals the value assigned by `(pkg_sig_1'range) <= z(pkg_sig_1'range);`.  So when the process is triggered at the change of `x`, the `tmp` will have the previous value in the `if tmp = 15 then ...`, and the new value of `tmp` is not assigned until after the process is completed.

Add `tmp` to the sensitivity list, or change `tmp` to a variable in the process, like:

```
process(x)
  variable tmp : integer;
begin
  tmp := to_integer(unsigned(x(3 downto 0)));
  if tmp = 15 then
    y <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(tmp, 8));
  else
    y <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this immediately.

Comment: One question (sry if stupid): does it remain synthetisable? I need a code which I can upload to an FPGA chip.

Comment: Yes, both suggested solutions are synthesizeable; sensitivity list is typically not used by synthesis tools, and the variable approach simply makes an intermediate signal in the netlist.

Comment: Thanks. Actually later on tmp will serve as an exponent of a floating point number, and I will have to shift the significand while incrementing/decrementing the exponent, and comparing it immediately after modification. That's why I couldn't add it to the sensitivity list. But knowing this, I'm afraid that I will have serious timing issues.